# Why doesn't Mathematica evaluate the series with recursion relationship as expected?

Tags: differential-equations, list-manipulation, series-expansion, recursion

I define a series $dg(i)$ as the $i$th derivative of a function $g[t]$ for $i>0$ and known the first term $dg(1)=(t-x)g(t)$. In mathematica, the code is:

```
dg[t_, i_] := D[dg[t, i - 1], t](*when i>1*);
dg[t_, 1] := (t - x) g[t];
```

Then I use

```
Table[{ii, dg[t, ii]}, {ii, 1, 5}] // TableForm //TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{cl}
>  1 & g(t) (t-x) \\
>  2 & (t-x) g'(t)+g(t) \\
>  3 & (t-x) g''(t)+2 g'(t) \\
>  4 & g^{(3)}(t) (t-x)+3 g''(t) \\
>  5 & g^{(4)}(t) (t-x)+4 g^{(3)}(t) \\
> \end{array}$

The question is why $g'(t)$ in the second term $dg(2)$ is not replaced by $(t-x) g(t)$? I need all the terms of the series is expressed only by $g(t)$ instead of $g'(t)$.

Could you help me? Thank you.

Comment: There is nothing in those definitions to connect `g'[t]` to `dg[1]`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I have modified the question to make it understandable. Thank you.

Comment: if dg(t) = (t-x)g(t) why would you use `D[]`? Just remove that

Answer (score 7):

```
Clear[g]
g /: g' = (# - x) g[#] &;
dg[t_, i_] := D[g[t], {t, i}]
Table[dg[t, i] // Simplify, {i, 1, 5}] // TableForm
```

[image]

These polynomials are essentially

```
Table[y^Floor[n/2] Sum[y^-i n!/(i! 2^i (n - 2 i)!), {i, 0, n/2}], {n, 0, 10}]
```

with `y=t-x`, up to a global factor of `g[t]`.

Comment: Thank you.  I am not familiar with ```TagSet[]``` and ```&```. They are very powerful. I  have tried your code. It is laconical and powerful! How about to get the explicit expression of $g^{(n)}(t)$ as the $n$th derivative of $g(t)$?

Comment: @tanghe2014 there you go.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to instead directly give definitions for the derivatives of `g`:

```
g' = (# - x) g[#]&;
Derivative[n_?Positive][g] := Derivative[n-1][g']
```

Then:

```
FullSimplify @ Column @ Table[Derivative[n][g][t], {n, 0, 5}] //TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{l}
>  g(t) \\
>  g(t) (t-x) \\
>  g(t) \left((t-x)^2+1\right) \\
>  g(t) \left((t-x)^2+3\right) (t-x) \\
>  g(t) \left((t-x)^4+6 (t-x)^2+3\right) \\
>  g(t) \left((t-x)^4+10 (t-x)^2+15\right) (t-x) \\
> \end{array}$

in agreement with Accidental's answer. With this approach, you can obtain the series expansions of `g` just using [`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series):

```
Series[g[t], {t, 0, 4}] //TeXForm
```

> $g(0)-g(0) t x+\frac{1}{2} t^2 \left(g(0) x^2+g(0)\right)+t^3 \left(-\frac{1}{6} g(0)
>    x^3-\frac{1}{2} g(0) x\right)+\frac{1}{24} t^4 \left(g(0) x^4+6 g(0) x^2+3
>    g(0)\right)+O\left(t^5\right)$

or

```
Series[g[t], {t, x, 4}] //TeXForm
```

> $g(x)+\frac{1}{2} g(x) (t-x)^2+\frac{1}{8} g(x) (t-x)^4+O\left((t-x)^5\right)$

Comment: Thank you. ```g' = (# - x) g[#]&``` is new for me and it is very helpful. Could you give more advice to get the general term of $g^{(n)}(t)$ as the $n$th derivative of $g(t)$?

Answer (score 5):

A simple method uses a `Rule[]` to replace `g'[t]` with its value:

```
ClearAll[x, g, dg];
dg[t_, 0] := g[t];
dg[t_, i_Integer /; i > 0] := D[dg[t, i - 1], t] /.
    g'[t] -> (t - x) g[t];
```

As a simple test try

```
dg[t, 5] // Simplify // InputForm
```

which returns the result

```
(15 + 10*(t - x)^2 + (t - x)^4)*(t - x)*g[t]
```

as it should.

Notice that in this method the derivative of `g` is completely contained in the `dg[]` rule. If you try `g'[t]` it get returned unevaluated. An alternative method is to attach the definition of `g'` directly to `g` itself. The code for this using a pure function is

```
g /: g' = Function[t, (t - x) g[t]];
```

Now we can use this definition directly so that

```
D[g[t], {t, n}] == dg[t, n]
```

evaluates to `True` for all $n \ge 0$.

The $n\,$th derivative of $g(t)$ is $g(t)$ multiplied by an $n\,$th degree polynomial in $(t-x)$ known as the modified Hermite polynomials -- the coefficients of which are given by the [OEIS sequence A099174](https://oeis.org/A099174). Thus, the following code

```
Expand[ dg[t, n] == g[t] HermiteH[n, I(t-x)/Sqrt[2]]
    (-I Sqrt[1/2])^n]
```

evaluates to `True` for all $n\ge 0.$ Note that using

```
DSolve[ g'[t] == (t - x)g[t] && g[0] == 1, g[t], t]
```

give the solution $\ g(t) = e^{t^2/2 - tx}\ $ which is the exponential generating function for modified Hermite polynomials.

Comment: Thank you. I get your point now. ```Rule[]``` is very helpful. Is it possible to get the general expression of $dg(t,n)$ using Mathematica?

Comment: @tanghe2014 If you mean by "using Mathematica" I have appended a general expression at the end of my answer.